# Angular $animate.enabled: disabling element's animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I've been running into trouble using the $animate.enabled method to programmatically disable and enable animation on a given element (via a directive). There are many solutions online that use this technique, so I can only assume I'm missing something, but I've tried writing it several different ways without success.

The $animate.enabled method is overloaded to perform two operations:

- `$animate.enabled(Boolean)`: Turns animation on or off globally.
- `$animate.enabled(Boolean, AngularElement)`: Turns animation on or off for the given element.

One would expect that if the global form disables animation successfully, the targetted form should do the same (for the targeted element), but here's an example of that not happening:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6if3nkgJdMHcnUrpcbVh?p=preview

For some people with similar problems, the issue ended up being that the first argument wasn't actually Boolean. Check the console on that plnkr to see that the argument is Boolean.

In my actual project, the directive I've written to do this looks like this:

```
cruncher.directive('crAnimateWhen', function($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.$eval(attr.crAnimateWhen);
            }, function(shouldAnimate) {
                $animate.enabled(shouldAnimate, elem);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The 'shouldAnimate' value is coming through loud and clear; it doesn't seem to be a problem with the attribute evaluation.

I'm aware that there are plenty of other approaches to selectively disabling angular animation (I've used them before, successfully). I'll probably just use one of those approaches -- but nonetheless I really want to know why the above code is failing.

---

*Edit: I should of course mention that I'm using Angular and ngAnimate 1.3.9 since this stuff is so often version related -- but the Plnkr is 1.3.0 and it's showing the same behavior.*

Comment: Reviewing the source code, it appears to be a real bug. At some point someone flipped "disabled" to "running" for the global value and the check value, but elements are still using "disabled" as the flag, and it appears it never gets checked. Can anyone confirm what I'm seeing?

Comment: Actually it looks like neither gets checked -- because when deciding if an element's animation is disabled, first it checks global and then it checks ... every parent, but never the element itself!? Of course this is dense bit of logic and I could be missing something, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: Consistent with that assessment, if I change it to $animate.enabled(shouldAnimate, elem.parent()) then it does in fact stop animation on the element. Inconsistent with that assessment, turning it back to true does not re-enable it. Whatever is happening here is weird.